# Postfix/Dovecot/Amavis allowing only mail to be received (and not sent)

Tags: linux, email, postfix

What is the best way to completely block outgoing mail on a linux server whilst still allowing incoming mail.

It seems this can't be done with port blocking and I have tried `smtpd_relay_restrictions = reject` in Postfix but this blocks everything.

There are easier to work with options in Dovecot but I'd like to create the block at a lower level if possible.

If outgoing mail can't be completely blocked then I would be satisfied with allowing mail to be sent to a single IP or domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to change

```
default_transport = smtp
```

to

```
default_transport = error:
```

in main.cf for Postfix